# Start same jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax function which gets data from another page..It is a kind of longpolling technique...I have given a timeout of 10 seconds.. and if the request gets canceled I am starting the function again...

```
function getContent(revision)
{

var queryString = {'revision': revision};

   var jqx = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'server.php',
            data: queryString,
        timeout: 10000,
            success: function(data){

                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                $('#response').html(obj.data_from_file);


            getContent(obj.revision);
            },
            error: function(){
            getContent(revision);
            },
        });



        };


$(document).ready(function(){
  getContent();
});
```

When I am calling the function again..a new request is sent in the console...But I want to send the same request..Like pause and start again....

What it's doing is stop and start again a new request..I want the same request to be paused and start..Is it possible? If yes, then how? If no, then why?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Your client(browser) sends the request and the request is processed on the server (server.php). When you send request again, server.php will again execute from the beginning not from the same place where the previous request stops.